# How do I delete a parquet file in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm writing to a parquet file in databricks, but before doing so, I'd like to delete the old version of it.

Here's my write line:

```
report.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").partitionBy("Name").parquet(s"s3://${reportBucket}/reports/dashboard")
```

I cannot figure out how to check for existence of this file, and delete if it exists.

Some pseudo code of the class, and the lines that calls it. I'm trying check if the output file exists, if it does, then remove it. Once it's removed, the class runs twice, and append the results to the parquet file. However, it must be only deleted after run2, and not run1.

```
class WriteReport(val run: String = "run1") {
val report = spark.read.parquet(s"blablah")
report.createOrReplaceTempView("report")

val dashboard = spark.sql (""" 
                SELECT name as Name from Table
                """)

report.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").partitionBy("Name").parquet(s"s3://${reportBucket}/reports/dashboard")
}

val n_b = new Report ("run1")
val n_g = new Report ("run2")
```

Comment: why not use the overwrite mode?

Answer (score 1):

> Spark doesn't provide support on S3 delete , you can work only under
> framwork and other outside framwork tasks you need to build own logic
> outside of Spark . Before trigger EMR you need to configure lamda to
> clean your dir and on confirm delete trigger Spark Job.

**Remove dir in local before recreate file :**

```
    import scala.reflect.io.Directory
    import java.io.File

    val dir = new Directory(new File("/yourDirectory"))
    dir.deleteRecursively()
```

**Remove dir in AWS  S3 before recreate file :**

AWS S3 has read-after-write consistency on PUTS objects ,eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES objects so once you delete will not remove same time and will take some time

So using S3 commonds and delete and run same time new job will get some issue , you need to build logic to create separate dir each time and delete once work done.

Java :

You need to use AWS sdk to delete as Spark not support any command delete from S3

```
    if (s3Client.doesBucketExist(bucketName)) {
                ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
                        .withBucketName(bucketName)
                        .withPrefix("foo/bar/baz");

                ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);

                while (true) {
                    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
                        s3Client.deleteObject(bucketName, objectSummary.getKey());
                    }
                    if (objectListing.isTruncated()) {
                        objectListing = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

BOTO S3 SDK :

```
     import boto3

     client = boto3.client('s3')
    client.delete_object(Bucket='mybucketname', Key='myfile.whatever')
```

Comment: Spark can interact with hadoop, Google storage and other file systems, and given its a big data processing tool it's unlikely that the data would reside in local file system.

Comment: GCP ,AWS and Azure has own SDK ,plz update question what cloud you are using

Comment: It's not my question, just noting this is unlikely to help. I'd imagine if there's a way of doing it using the spark api and letting spark handle the file system that would be a good answer as it'll support whatever spark supports.

Comment: Spark doesn't provide support on S3 delete , you can work only under framwork and other outside framwork  tasks you need to build own logic outside of Spark . Before trigger EMR you need to configure lamda to clean your dir and on confirm delete you trigger Spark Job

Comment: Ah that's really useful information! Could you add that spark doesn't support delete on s3 to your answer, and maybe give an answer for hadoop if you know how to do it on hdfs as hdfs is pretty common.

Comment: @vaquarkhan, If spark doesn't provide support on S3 delete, then what's Mode.Overwrite option is about ?